# Refined triangulation for simplicial spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I just started learning algebraic topology, with almost no background in homology.

My supervisor mentioned the following result to me:

> If $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous map between simplicial spaces
> (manifolds equipped with triangulation),
>
> then there exists a refined
> triangulation with respect to $f$ (i.e. vertices mapped to vertices, edges mapped to edges, faces mapped to faces).

However after a bit of googling, I am still not sure what this theorem is called and how to prove it.

I thought since triangulation approximates the manifold, perhaps I can use some standard analysis tools about the convergence of sequences in each space.

I am not sure how much homology I need in order to understand this theorem.

Any hints will be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: The result you're looking for is the "simplicial approximation theorem."

Comment: "there exists a refined triangulation" - of $X$ or of $Y$ or of both?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Not really. Simplicial approximation only works up to homotopy. Here we should not change $f$, but triangulations.